# JavaScript/AJAX - Returning object in onreadystatechange (undefined error)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to return an object in the onreadtstatechange function when making an AJAX request. I assign the returned object to a variable, but when i try to access the variable, I get this error (after trying to use the description property of the object):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined

Here is what I'm doing:

```
var myApp = function() {

 var obj1 = function() {
    return {
        something:function() {

            var xmlhttp;

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    return {
                        status:xmlhttp.status,
                        description:xmlhttp.responseText
                    }
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://something",true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    }
 }();

 var obj2 = function() {
    return {
        something2:function() {
            var something = obj1.something();
            console.log("Description: "+something.description + ", Status: "+something.status);
        }
    }
 }();

}();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/) (the 2nd answer is edited for library-less Ajax)

Comment: that link jonathan posted does sum it up pretty good

Comment: store response in a variable `var data=xmlhttp.responseText`  and then parse it `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'm gonna try passing the callback to the function as the answer explains. The only problem is that my function has like 6 different states, so i'm gonna have to pass the 6 functions

Comment: I have one question. In the example i posted, how can I reference xmlhttp from function something2? I want to build the function in something2, and pass it to something, but I'm not sure how I'm suppose to reference xmlhttp.status from something2

Comment: Sorry, I found the answer to that question in the other post